# Cannot call method 'charAt' of undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, less-rails

I am having rails3 application which running fine in my local ubuntu machine. I deployed my application using capistrano-unicorn to remote server via copy. The remote server is also having a same configuration which I had in local machine like

```
rvm 1.16.17
ruby 1.9.3p286
Rails 3.2.8
less 2.2.2
less-rails 2.2.6
less-rails-bootstrap 2.2.0
```

My Gemfile

```
group :assets do
  gem 'less-rails-bootstrap'
  gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'uglifier'
end
```

I am getting an error

> Less::Error in User/home#index Cannot call method 'charAt' of
>   undefined   (in
>   /home/user/rails_app_development/releases/20121102052832/app/assets/stylesheets/layout.css.less)

Where I am doing wrong here?

Comment: look at your layout.css.less and find method called 'charAt'?

Comment: I have the same problem.  Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error appeared in our project too. It happened because we had only the `mixins.less` imported, but not the `variables.less` of twitter bootstrap.

Importing `variables.less` **right before** the `mixins.less` solved the problem like magic.